# How to replace characters in the same position in each line of a text with natural numbers?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a multi-line repeating text like this, each line is same.

```
aaa0bbb
aaa0bbb
...
aaa0bbb
```

How can I change it to

```
aaa0bbb
aaa1bbb
...
aaa2bbb
```

I tried to use awk or sed to handle it, but it's hard to me.

Comment: Even if your solution doesn't work or looks terrible, I recommend posting it here anyway so that people can see you've put forth some effort :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Perl, just specify the pattern in brackets aaa0bbb as (aaa)(0)(bbb) in the below one-liner.

```
$ cat mkb.txt
aaa0bbb
aaa0bbb
def
ghi
aaa0bbb
aaa0bbb
$ perl -pe  ' s/(aaa)(0)(bbb)/sprintf("%s%d%s",$1,$kv{"$1$2$3"}++,$3)/ge ' mkb.txt
aaa0bbb
aaa1bbb
def
ghi
aaa2bbb
aaa3bbb
$
```

Comment: Thanks, perl works pretty good.

Comment: glad that it worked!!.. please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like in `awk` may do the work

```
awk 'BEGIN {i=0} {printf("%s%c%s\n", substr($0, 1, 3), i, substr($0, 5, length($0) - 4));i++}' inputfile
```

NB! After 10-nt row the number will have two digits and so on.